# WIX page UTM_SOURCE

Tags: email, utm, velo

How can I add UTM_SOURCE to my WIX page.
I have a WIX page and am running multiple facebook campaigns and google adwords, that direct customers to that page. 
I send myself an email with the form information entered on that page. I would like to add the UTM_SOURCE to this email so I can track which campaigns are most effective. How do I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add it to your URL. For example if your website url is www.mysite.com then your final URL should be:

www.mysite.com?utm_source=campaignName

If you have Google Analytics, it will automatically pull the value of the utm_source